# how to read a json stringfied object in servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I have a 2 dimensional array in javascript

```
arr[0][0]=1
arr[0][1]=2
arr[1][0]=3
arr[1][1]=4
```

Now i am converting the above array into a JSON String and setting this value to a hidden paramater

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
document.form2.hiddenValue2.value=jsonString;
```

In Servlet when i print the value of the JSON string it is displayed as below

```
String ab = request.getParameter("hiddenValue2");
System.out.println("ab"+ab);
//Output is
[["1","2"],["3","4"]]
```

My Question is how can i parse the above json string into java array or whatever is easy to proceed further with the values of the json String. 
I have checked similar questions but couldnt find a correct solution..
 Help me..!!

Comment: You'll need a JSON parser.

Comment: I am new to JSON and have no idea how to parse it.. I have checked some solutions and tried using JSONSerializer.toJSON. I am getting invalid JSON String error. i doubt if that is the correct way of parsing..? Can you please correct me..

Comment: No, you need a parser *from* JSON to a Java object.

Comment: Can you give me any example please..